# Select div with random class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-ui-slider

I'am using iosslider on my single page.
I need to collect all img src from '.wp-pic' and put them to slider background url.
So what I have:

SLIDER FRAME AND DIV WITH WP PICTURES:

```
<div class='my-slider large-9 columns'>
  <div class='sliderContainer'>
    <div class='iosSlider'>
      <div class='slider'>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!--/.slider-->

<div class='wp-pic'>
  <?php if(have_posts()) : ?> 
    <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
       <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>

/* SLIDER SETTINGS
=============================================*/
.sliderContainer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.iosSlider{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.iosSlider .slider{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.iosSlider .slider .item{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

// REMOVE PICTURES PUSHED BY WP AND PUT THEM TO THE IOSSLIDER
  $('.wp-pic').find('img').each(function(){
    var photoSrc  = $(this).attr('src'),
        photoImg  = '<img src="' + photoSrc + '">',
        numbClass = Math.round(Math.random() * 15);
    $('.slider').append('<div class="item photo-template' + numbClass + '">' + photoImg + '</div>');
    $('.wp-pic').remove();
  });

  $('.item').find('img').each(function(){
    var x = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.slider').find('div:contains(photo-template)').each(function(){ 
      $(this).css({
        'background-image'   :'url(' + x + ')',
        'background-size'    :'contain',
        'background-position':'center',
        'background-repeat'  :'no-repeat'
      });
    });
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

How can I select each class 'photo-template' and place on their background collected src?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7a5sh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to have different classes to do what you want.

and you can get it with only one loop. Just loop through each img and then change it's parent's css.

```
$('.item').find('img').each(function(){
    var x = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).parent().css({
        'background-image'   :'url(' + x + ')',
        'background-size'    :'contain',
        'background-position':'center',
        'background-repeat'  :'no-repeat'
    });
    $(this).remove();
});
```

look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PyTn4/2/) i've made based on yours.

Comment: My one suggestion would be to use `this.src` rather than jQuery's `attr()` method.

Comment: @DavidThomas I think it's better to keep using jQuery. Mixing jQuery and pure javascript can be a little confusing.

Comment: Well, it's your answer and needless complexity, so fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.each() on `$(".photo-template")`, which will return each element with that class.

Format:

```
$.each( $(".photo-template"), function(el, i) {
  // do something with $(el).find("img").attr("src")
};
```

Comment: I already do this, as you can see class photo-template every time looks diferent - becouse I generate to it a numberClass. 

I haven't .photo-template, I have some random class which looks like "photo-template + Math.round(Math.random() * 15)"